# how to balance mixed tungsten and daylight in a showroom?

Tags: lighting, studio-lighting, lighting-basics

Location: interior showroom (mixed tungsten and day light from show window) How do you balance the light? please explain

I am an engineering student taking a non technical elective course about cinema.

I am struggling with this lighting assignment since i have no background in lighting at all.

the question is exactly like i typed it above, i wish there was more information to help solving this question

the answer does not have to be very detailed

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have four options:

1) cover the windows with warming gels to match the tungsten lighting

2) cover the windows completely

3) shoot early or late in the day as the sun is rising or setting (golden hour)

4) replace the tungsten lighting with daylight balance bulbs

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to take two photos, one with white balance set for daylight and the other with white balance set for tungsten, and overlay the two in separate layers in Photoshop (or Photoshop Elements, I think).  The you erase the portions of the image that are lit by the tungsten, using a blended edge where the two area meet.  This takes a bit of work and you'll need to understand the basics of using layers in Photoshop, but you can get a vey good rendering this way if you have the time.